# odoo (v16) resize of pdf_viewer in invoice preview does not work

Tags: odoo, resize, pdf-viewer

i am new to odoo v16, my first task is related to the invoice preview,  the resize of the preview does not work,
due to being pressed by the customer an being really new to the new javascript framework on v16, has anybody idea how to fix the resizing feature?